# Vuex parameter passing

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

```
this.$store.commit(
  'deleteCheckboxItems',
   response.data.items.forEach(element => {
     element.id;
     })
   );
```

from the received `api` I need to get the id and pass it to vuex. The function works, but it writes undefined in the console when called.

**vuex:**

```
 deleteCheckboxItems(state, payload) {
  if(state.filteredBrands) {
    state.filteredBrands = state.filteredBrands.filter((item) => {
      console.log(payload);
      item.id == payload;
    });
  }
```

In vuex I need `id` to compare, if there are the same then delete.
What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` function instead of `forEach`:

```
this.$store.commit(
  'deleteCheckboxItems',
   response.data.items.map(({id}) => id)
);
```

Your `filter` function also needs some changes. It should return a boolean, but you forgot to return the value.

```
deleteCheckboxItems(state, payload) {
  console.log(payload);
  if (state.filteredBrands) {
    state.filteredBrands = state.filteredBrands.filter((item) => {
      return item.id == payload;
    });
  }
}
```

Also payload maybe an array of ids, and you should use some functions like `includes` to check your condition.

Comment: Ok, with ```map``` my vuex got array with ```id```, but it still clears the entire array and not the values ​​that were passed. I mean my function in ``vuex`` doesn't work the way i would like

Comment: Answer updated. @Alex

Comment: big thanks! And i used ```return !payload.includes(item.id);```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to change your implementation of `deleteCheckboxItems`to take an array wrap the `this.$store.commit`with the for each like this:
`response.data.items.forEach(element => { this.$store.commit('deleteCheckboxItems', element) });`

Furthermore, the more important one is that your `filteredBrands.filter`does not filter since you do not return a value. You have to `return item.id === payload`.